# Disable sleep mode after 5 minutes

Tags: suspend, login-screen

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my laptop. When I have my laptop plugged in to my tv to watch a movie, the screen goes black after exactly 5 minutes. I have to move the mouse, to see I'm at the login screen like this

[image]

I'm wondering how can I disable this screen from popping up entirely?

I have already went to  System -> Power Management and put everything at Don't suspend / Do nothing. This did not work!!

Comment: Caffeine? http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/12/screensaver-stopper-caffeine-gets-first-update-two-years

Comment: if you use `sleepd` then stop service `sudo service sleepd stop`

Answer (score 16):

Change both "System Settings -> Brightness & Lock" and "System Settings -> Power Settings"

Answer (score 2):

If someone is using Gnome, this can be accomplished using the Caffeine Gnome extension

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/

I'm not sure if Unity has something similar or not.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but you might want to expand it with information about how to install/enable Caffeine on an Ubuntu system that's running GNOME.

Comment: You visit that page from Firefox while running gnome shell and you should see a button towards the top left that says "off".  click the button to turn it to the 'On' setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Xubuntu and I did this:

```
xset -display :0 s off -dpms
```

It is not persistent though and since I dont want it to be I did this:

*Add this command to your startup applications:*

```
sh -c "sleep 30; xset -display :0 s off -dpms"
```

You can change the sleep time to whatever you want even remove it.