# Ubuntu 16.04 Kodi application

Tags: 16.04, touchscreen, kodi

I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop that is connected to my TV and I have Kodi installed to open on boot in full screen, but the problem I'm having is if I don't touch the pad on the laptop the Kodi app will close I guess like a screen saver comes on but it just goes to a black screen. I'm new to Ubuntu and I can't find where to go to keep screen on at all times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable sleep mode after 5 minutes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/508532/disable-sleep-mode-after-5-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can go to all settings and search for power in the search bar. You can change the sleep time from there.